# Fetch data from api every second

Tags: javascript, react-native, express, react-hooks, fetch

I have a react native app where i am fetching orders made by customer and display them in restaurant side in a specific screen, I am using fetch api to get the data,
so THE WORKFLOW is customer first place order and store it in database and in the restaurant side i have this function :

```
  const loadData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/getActiveOrders?ID=${id}`);
        const result = await response.json();
        if (result.auth === true) {

                setCurrentOrders(result.data)

        } else {
            setCurrentOrders([])
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            loadData();
        }, 1000)
        return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }, [id]);
```

as in this function it runs every second and it makes api call to express server to fetch the data from database so i keep restaurant receiving orders without delay. But i noticed that the app is lagging when the interval set to 1 second and it keep making frequent calls to the express server.

**my question:** Is this the best approach  to perform same as this scenario (fetching the orders the moment they been placed by the customer) or Is there a better way to do it without lagging as well as when fetching large data will the performance remain the same or there will be some issues?

Comment: I don't think you want `CurrentOrders` as a dependency for your `useEffect`. Maybe `id` since it's used in `loadData`

Comment: @Phil thanks for this notice, i will update my code, anyway Do you have any idea about my concern ? thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I had to guess what the cause of the lagging issue was it would be because you have a dependency on the `useEffect` hook. Each time the state updates it triggers another render and the effect runs again, and sets up another interval, and your app is doing this once every second.

I suggest removing the dependency and run the effect only once when the component mounts, and clearing the interval when unmounting.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    loadData();
  }, 1000)
  return () => clearInterval(interval)
}, []);
```

If the `id` for the GET requests updates and you need the latest value, then use a React ref to store the `id` value and use this in the request URL.

```
const idRef = React.useRef(id);

useEffect(() => {
  idRef.current = id;
}, [id]);

const loadData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/getActiveOrders?ID=${idRef.current}`);
  const result = await response.json();
  setCurrentOrders(result.auth ? result.data : []);
}
```

Comment: Actually the id always remain  the same  so i think removing dep is the best way.

Answer (score 3):

You should use websockets in this case. This is the best scenario to use websockets. Your scenario is just like a trading website.

Comment: I agree with you on this, websocket is the best approach here. But I think this should be a comment rather than a answer

Comment: I have given this as an answer because the implementation of the scenario was not correct. It could break the system and it will cost a lot (if it is a managed service). Websockets here will save lot of money plus there will be smooth transaction of data. It can easily be scalable also.

Comment: Yes, your use case definitely require websocket.